# Windows 10 automatically update the modified time of installer files while it has been executed

Tags: timestamp

Windows 10 automatically update the modified time of installer files while it has been executed.
I have tried some installers and most of those modified time have been updated, now these files' timestamp are messed up, I want to know any idea to fix this? I dont want my installers' timestamp been updated. thanks.

Comment: From the post i got to know that you are taking backup for either file or disk image.If you don't mind may i know what backup software you are using to take backup?.

Comment: @vembutech sorry for bad english, I edited my problems again, would you mind checked it again.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, too.  I was able to fix it mostly but it still seems to happen occasionally, and not necessarily only with installers.  It happens with .exe and .lnk files mostly.  The problem with installer files, I think, has to do with the indicator that says this file came from another computer/internet.  You can check off the unblock this file in properties of the particular file.

To fix this for all the files you have downloaded use the streams utility (available at sysinternals) on the directory where the installer files are: streams -s -d directory

To fix it for future downloads run regedit and set/create SaveZoneInformation 2
in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments